# Find the red coloured area

Tags: geometry

A circle is in a square of side 10 and a quadrant circle with radius 10 overlaps as shown in the figure. Find the red coloured area.

$\hskip2.4in$[image]

I guess I could find the value by subtracting the area of circles from that of the square, but I can't because of the overlapping part.

Comment: Do you know integrals and equation of circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red area can be viewed as a trapezoid minus a triangle and  two circular sectors.

[image]

Letting $O=(0,0)$ and $B=(1,1)$ we easily obtain $$P=\left({\sqrt{7}-1\over4},{\sqrt{7}+1\over4}\right)\ ,$$ so that the angles of the two sectors become
$$\alpha=\arcsin{\sqrt{7}-1\over4},\quad \beta=\arcsin{5-\sqrt{7}\over8}\ .$$
The triangle $OAP$ has area
$${1\over2}\>\vec{OA}\>\wedge\>\vec{OP}={1\over2} \ (1,-1)\wedge\left({\sqrt{7}-1\over4},{\sqrt{7}+1\over4}\right)={\sqrt{7}\over4}\ ,$$
and the encompassing trapezoid obviously has area ${3\over2}$.

At the end we have to multiply everything with $25$, so that we obtain
$${\rm red\ area}=25\left({3\over2}-{\sqrt{7}\over4}-{1\over2}\arcsin{\sqrt{7}-1\over4}-2\arcsin{5-\sqrt{7}\over8}\right)\doteq0.728506\ .$$

Comment: That looks pretty ugly. Are $ \angle MOP, BAP$ "nice"? Generally, with this type of questions, I expect there to be a nice way of doing it. Though of course, that need not be the case.

Comment: @Calvin Lin: Let's wait for the definitive answer. Then we shall see whether it is "simple".

Comment: Solving the equations $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ and $(5-x)^2 + (y + 5)^2 = 100$ gives $x = \frac{\sqrt{175} - 5}{4}$, $y = \frac{\sqrt{175} + 5}{4}$

Comment: @user73985 It might be easier to set the problem up as I have done with the lower left vertex of the square at (0,0) then the problem is just an area between two curves. Please see my post.

Comment: @Leun Park Why have you not even looked at my solution? It is after all the only one and has been sitting there for 2 days. Other posts and comments have been upvoted but mine ignored. I do not care about the vote but a nothing here is tantamount to a downvote. Is my solution wrong? Is it offensive? Then I will remove it. Some feedback would be nice, I am learning and asking questions too. Very discouraging not even to get any criticism.

Answer (score 4):

@Leun Park

I can provide an approximation in case no one can get the exact answer and you need some answer.

$ \frac{1}{2} \left(100-\left(\frac{100 \pi }{4}+14.6381259\, +\frac{1}{4} (100-25 \pi )\right)\right)\approx .7285$

I think it is close.

Or notice the piece on the left is the same as the red piece. Now just get the intersection points of the arc and the circle and integrate between the two equations.

$\text{Area}=\int_0^{\frac{5}{4} \left(3-\sqrt{7}\right)} \left(5-\sqrt{10 x-x^2}\right) \, dx-\int_0^{\frac{5}{4} \left(3-\sqrt{7}\right)} \sqrt{20 x-x^2} \, dx $

$=\frac{1}{4} (-25) \left(-6+\sqrt{7}+10 \pi -4 \tan ^{-1}\left(2+\sqrt{7}\right)-16 \tan ^{-1}\left(4+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)$

$=.72850589607829715$

which agrees with my approximation.

Comment: Oh no, that's not it. It's just that I'm not a native English speaker nor good in maths that I didn't leave a feedback. I'm really sorry and thank you so much for your solution!!

Answer (score 1):

An integral approach:

Call the red area $A$, then:
$$ A = \{(x,y)^2 \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \le x \le 10, 5 \le y \le 10, (x-10)^2+y^2 \ge 10^2, (x-5)^2 + (y-5)^2 \ge 5^2\}$$

(where you can change all $\le$ to $\lt$, if you don‘t want to "count the border", it won‘t change the result.) How did I get to this formula? Well, the first two conditions should be obvious. The formula for a circle with radius $r$ centered in $(x_0,y_0)$ is $((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2 = r^2$ and the red area is $above$ two circles.

The following requires some knowledge about the Lebesgue integral as [Tonelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) will be used. Though I hope most of it should be understandable with less knowledge.

The area of $A$ is $\int_A 1 \mathrm{d}(x,y)$.

$$ 
\int_A 1 \mathrm{d}(x,y)
= \int_5^{10} \int_{\varphi(y)}^{10} 1 \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
= \int_5^{10} 10 - \varphi(y) \mathrm{d}y
$$

where $\varphi(y)$ gives the smallest $x$ for which $(x,y) \in A$. This is true because of the upper and lower bounds of the $x$ and $y$ values.

Two steps are remaining:

1. Find $\varphi(y)$ for all $y \in [5,10]$ To do so, write the conditions in the definition of $A$ as “$x \ge max(\dots,\dots)$”.
2. Solve the resulting one-dimensional integral. Honestly I do not know whether this is an easy task, as I have not done 1. (yet?). Hopefully you find an anti derivative here! (You should be able to assume the integral is a Riemann integral.)

Comment: Postpones the bulk of the work.

Comment: Ah, well. 1-dimensional integration shows that the area of $A$ is $\int_5^{10} 10 - \varphi(y) \mathrm{d}y$, I see. So Tonelli and Lebesgue are not used here. But at least I gave a hint how to determine $\varphi(y)$.

Comment: Yeah, as the pointwise minimum of two functions, even the point where they meet being not obvious...